# Drag QListWidgetItem out of QListWidget

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I would like to drag a `QListWidgetItem` out of `QListWidget`. I'm making a program to create a soccer line up by dragging players (label with pixmap) around. I want to drag players from the "bench" to the "outfield", where the user can drag them freely in a soccer formation:

program on start:
[image: program on start]

dragging players between the "bench" and the "outfield":
[image: dragging players between the left hand side and the right hand side]

I thought about using labels with pixmap for the "outfield" players, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use `QListWidgetItem` out of `QListWidget`. Is there a better way to do this?

Code:

```
import json
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        class MovableLabel(QLabel):
            """WToolBar is a personalized toolbar."""

            homeAction = None

            oldPos = QPoint()

            def __init__(self, mainWindow : MainWindow, filename: str):
                super().__init__(mainWindow)
                self.mainWindow = mainWindow
                self.filename = filename
                self.clicked = False

            def mousePressEvent(self, evt):
                """Select the toolbar."""
                self.oldPos = evt.globalPos()
                if not self.clicked:
                    globalPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
                    self.setParent(self.mainWindow)
                    self.move(self.mapFromGlobal(globalPos))
                    self.raise_()
                    self.show()
                    self.clicked = True
                    self.grabMouse()

            def mouseMoveEvent(self, evt):
                """Move the toolbar with mouse iteration."""
                delta = QPoint(evt.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
                self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
                self.oldPos = evt.globalPos()

            def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
                self.releaseMouse()
                self.clicked = False
                if ev.globalPos().x() < listWidget.width():
                    if self in self.mainWindow.players:
                        self.mainWindow.players.remove(self)
                if self not in self.mainWindow.players:
                    self.mainWindow.players.append(self)

        self.players = []
        pixmap = QPixmap()

        class MyItem(QListWidgetItem):
            def __init__(self, label : MovableLabel):
                super(MyItem, self).__init__()
                self.label = label

        class MyListWidget(QListWidget):
            def __init__(self, mainWindow : MainWindow):
                super(MyListWidget, self).__init__(mainWindow)
                self.mainWindow = mainWindow

            def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
                item = self.selectedItems()[0]
                imageSize = item.icon().actualSize(QSize(100, 200))
                self.removeItemWidget(item)
                label = MovableLabel(self.mainWindow, 'Pogba.jpg')
                pixmap = item.icon().pixmap(imageSize)
                label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                label.setFixedSize(imageSize)
                label.move(e.globalPos())
                label.show()

        listWidget = MyListWidget(self)
        listWidget.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        listWidget.setFixedSize(500, 700)
        listWidget.setIconSize(QSize(100, 200))
        listWidget.setDragDropMode(listWidget.InternalMove)


        '''json file contains positions of "outfield" players'''
        try:
            with open('players.txt', 'r') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
        except:
            data = []

        dir = 'Players/'

        for filename in os.listdir(dir):
            pixmap = QPixmap(dir + filename).scaledToHeight(100, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            label = MovableLabel(self, filename)
            label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            label.setFixedSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

            playersIndex = next((i for i, player in enumerate(data) if player['filename'] ==
                                 filename), None)
            if playersIndex == None:
                item = QListWidgetItem(QIcon(dir + filename), '<Name>', listWidget)
            else:
                label.setParent(self)
                label.move(data[playersIndex]['x'], data[playersIndex]['y'])
                self.players.append(label)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.showMaximized()

    def closeEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QCloseEvent) -> None:
        with open('players.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump([{'filename': player.filename, 'x': player.x(), 'y': player.y()} for player in self.players],
                      outfile, indent= 4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

**Edit:**

I've tried to implement using label with pixmap when dragging the `QListWidgetItem` out the `QListWidget`, but the listWidgetItem won't disappear from the listWidget, I can't get the label to align with the item as it were it (I just moved the label to where the cursor is), and I'm unsure how to replace the player to the listWidget. What event is triggered when the item is dragged out the listWidget? Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a QListView (using the `IconMode`) instead of a layout with widgets?

Comment: Will try it. Thanks

Comment: How do I do that? Google's not giving me anything and Qt doc doesn't say much about IconMode.

Comment: I don't know what keywords you are using or what documentation you're looking, but it's all in the QListView documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop Note that for your use case, you can even use a QListWidget (which inherits QListView), so that you don't need to use a model.

Comment: Thanks. What is a model?

Comment: See [Model-view-controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), then carefully read and study [Model/View programming in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html); as a programmer, you *must* know and understand what is a model, and if you use Qt you *must* know how they work and what they do (even if you don't normally use them).

Comment: I'm really struggling to drag item out of listwidget... Please could you help a brother out here?